# Issue with SQL Connection Class in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Any idea why I would be getting an error with SqlConnection Saying Type Expected Code BC30182 , Its almost like its not importing System.Data.SqlClient. I am using vs 2015.

```
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class SQLControl

    Public SQLCon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;DataBase=DBname;Trusted_Connection=True;"}
    Public SQLcmd As SqlCommand

    Public Function HasConnection() As Boolean
        Try
            SQLCon.open

            SQLCon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Compiles fine in .net fiddle (after adding `Imports System`, which should not be required in a Visual Studio VB project). What *exactly* does the error message say?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8s7i7g Here is a Screenshot of VS

Comment: Do you have a reference to System.Data.dll in your project?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same but it SqlCommand works so shouldn't SqlConnection ?  http://prntscr.com/8s7jnm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The screenshot you posted in the comments](http://prntscr.com/8s7i7g) reveals that your project is called `SqlConnection`. Thus, your default namespace is also `SqlConnection` (unless you changed it). Thus, when you type `SqlConnection`, the compiler assumes that you mean the namespace rather than the class.

You have two options to fix this:

1. In your project properties, change your default namespace to something else, e.g. `Wally.SqlConnectionProject`.

or

2. use the full type name including the namespace, i.e., `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`.

Comment: Bingo, I renamed the project MSSqlConnection and the issue went away. Good thing i had a screenshot. Thanks for your time Heinzi